# only one event from google calendar is being shown on fullcalendar on my site

Tags: fullcalendar

I have an instance of full calendar running on my site. I am using a google calendar to run it. I have the updated gcal.js file, and I have set up the code as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: {
      googleCalendarApiKey: 'MYAPIKEY',
      googleCalendarId:  'MYCALENDARID',
      className: 'fc-event-email'
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

The calendar is importing one reoccurning event per month, but nothing else.

Some other things I have checked: 
all events are public
I have erased events and re-added them to see if they appear.
re-downloading and updating the full calendar JS on my page.

Can anyone help point me to the right direction as to only why one event is importing?

EDIT: updated code to reflect code, I accidentally inserted out dated version in original post. Issue is the same for both instances however.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's significant but I would expect you should write `events:` instead of `eventSources:` in the case that you only have one source. I think eventSources is supposed to be specified as an array rather than an object.

Comment: But I'm not sure that's the real issue. Have you checked your browser's network tool to see the request going to Google Calendar, and looked in the response to see how many events are returned by that?

Comment: thank you @ADyson. 

I checked the network, and only one event was indeed being returned. Helping me narrow it down to the google side of things. 
I  recently had shared the calendar, and the id changed for the calendar, the old ID only imported items added by one individual, hence only one event being imported.

Also on a side note, after updating, eventSources is working ok.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the network, and only one event was indeed being returned. Helping me narrow it down to the google side of things. I recently had shared the calendar, and the id changed for the calendar, the old ID only imported items added by one individual, hence only one event being imported. Also on a side note, after updating, eventSources is working ok.